# Difference between String.indexOf(int x) and String.indexOf(String)

Tags: java, string

There are two methods in the `String` class that look like they do the same thing:

- `indexOf(int)`
- `indexOf(String)`

Can someone please explain what the difference between these two functions is?

Comment: read the javadoc. this type of questions are not welcome in this community, i.e. you can easily read about these methods with google search. read about _overloading_, too.

Comment: To be fair, it can be slightly confusing that it takes an `int` where most people would expect `char`

Comment: @BradMace - but I'm sure that the javadoc explains that too.  The point is that a Java programmer should **always** check the javadoc first for a question like this.

Answer (score 5):

- **`String.indexOf(int)`**: `Returns the index within this string of the
  first occurrence of the specified character`.
- **`String.indexOf(String)`**: `Returns the index within this string of the
  first occurrence of the specified substring`.

Example:

```
String test = "aaabbbaaabbb";
test.indexOf('a') return 0 (first 'a' in string)
test.indexOf('b') return 3 (first 'a' in string)
test.indexOf("aaa") return 0 (first "aaa" in string)
test.indexOf("bbb") return 3 (first "bbb" in string)
test.indexOf("sajx") return -1 (not found)
```

Comment: +1 for showing how the String.indexof(int) method can be used to locate the position of a specific character.

Answer (score 0):

```
indexOf(int ch)
```

Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character.

This will help you to identify the index of character present in String.

```
indexOf(String str)
```

Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring.

This will help you to identify the index of substring present in String.

Comment: -1, the OP can read the API himself (you can't program if you don't know how to read the API). If the OP has a specific question about something they don't understand in the API description then they should ask a specific question about what they read.

Comment: It doesn't mean the person who is explaining in easy language then what mentioned in doc should get negative vote. Negative vote specifically means that this answer is not useful, is that the case here????

Comment: You basically just copied the text from the API. I don't consider the answer useful because that information is found in the API. The OP should be reading the API first.

Comment: @camickr: if you read the answer carefully, you can see the last line for both the API i explained is not from API and I mentioned what I know correct of that API. bellabax, wrote the same that is in API. that too samples that person can get through google, so he should get negative vote for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = "abcdefabc";            
    System.out.println(str.indexOf(97)); //97 is int value of 'a'.
     //so this will return first occurrence of 'a'
    System.out.println(str.indexOf("b")); // this will return first 
    //occurrence of "b" in the String
```

Answer (score -1):

**String.indexOf(int ch)**

Returns the index within this string of the first 
 occurrence of the specified character. If a character 
 with value ch occurs in the character sequence 
 represented by this String object, then the index (in 
 Unicode code units) of the first such occurrence is 
 returned.

**String.indexOf(String str)**

if the string argument occurs as a substring within 
this object, then the index of the first character of the 
first such substring is returned; if it does not occur as a 
substring, -1 is returned.

Comment: -1 for duplicate answer. No need to clutter the forum with various rewordings of the API.